# Не могу создать проект в Visual Studio 2017, ошибка 0x80041fe2

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Хотел создать проект просто пустой на в VS.Но выходит такая ошибка.Кто знает ? В чем проблема ? Как решить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слишком мало данных для ответа. Попробуйте указать версию windows, студии, указать возникает ли ошибка при любом проекте (лучше снимите видео, какие кнопки жмёте). Также попробуйте [погуглить текст ошибки](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=0x80041fe2%20visual%20studio%202017&lr=213&clid=2186621), видели [например это](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/exception-from-hresult-0x80041fe2-when-creating-new-project/27148) или [это](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104671/error-exception-hresult-0x80041fe2.html), пробовали переустанавливать  Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015?

Comment: Спасибо за совет ! Переустановил Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015.Помогло )

Answer (score 3):

Первая ссылка по вашей ошибке ведёт к репорту https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104671/error-exception-hresult-0x80041fe2.html

Вам надо установить/переустановить “Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64”